# How to change the state of a button in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to learn basics of Tkinter module, such as making buttons, checkboxes and other basic widgets. I wanted to make a window with two checkboxes "music" and "video", and a button "proceed", such that the button is 'enabled' only when "music" checkbox is checked. On searching a little bit more about the topic, I cam across tracers, but I am unable to understand the following definition of function callme(ie the use of * in the arguements).
I am using ubuntu 12.04 and using python 2.7 The code that I typed is given below.

```
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter
top = Tkinter.Tk()
CheckVar1 = Tkinter.IntVar()
CheckVar2 = Tkinter.IntVar()
C1 = Tkinter.Checkbutton(top, text = "Music", variable = CheckVar1, \
         onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=5, \
         width = 20)
C2 = Tkinter.Checkbutton(top, text = "Video", variable = CheckVar2, \
         onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=5, \
         width = 20)
def callme(* args):
   if args[2] == 'w':
   b1['state'] = 'normal'    
def exit():
    pass
b1 = Tkinter.Button(top, text = "Proceed", command = exit)
b1['state'] = 'disabled'
C1.pack()
C2.pack()
b1.pack() 
CheckVar1.trace("w", callme) 
CheckVar2.trace("w", callme)
top.mainloop()
```

Also, can somebody tell me how do I pass more arguments to the callme function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`callme` should read as follow:

```
def callme(*args):
    if CheckVar1.get() or CheckVar2.get():
        b1['state'] = 'normal'
    else:
        b1['state'] = 'disabled'
```

### how do I pass more arguments to the callme function

Use `lambda`:

```
def callme(msg, extra1, extra2):
    print msg, extra1, extra2
    if CheckVar1.get() or CheckVar2.get():
        b1['state'] = 'normal'
    else:
        b1['state'] = 'disabled'
...

CheckVar1.trace("w", lambda *args: callme('checkvar1 changed', 'blah', 'blah'))
CheckVar2.trace("w", lambda *args: callme('checkvar2 changed', 'xxx', 'yyy'))
```